# Can't override __init__ of class from Cython extension

Tags: python, inheritance, cython

I am trying to subclass [pysam's `Tabixfile`](http://www.cgat.org/~andreas/documentation/pysam/api.html#pysam.Tabixfile) class and add additional attributes on instantiation.

```
class MyTabixfile(pysam.Tabixfile):

    def __init__(self, filename, mode='r', *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(filename, mode=mode, *args, **kwargs)
        self.x = 'foo'
```

When I try to instantiate my `MyTabixfile` subclass, I get a `TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters`:

```
>>> mt = MyTabixfile('actn2-oligos-forward.tsv.gz')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-11-553015ac7d43>", line 1, in <module>
    mt = MyTabixfile('actn2-oligos-forward.tsv.gz')
  File "mytabix.py", line 4, in __init__
    super().__init__(filename, mode=mode, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

I also tried calling the `Tabixfile` constructor explicitly:

```
class MyTabixfile(pysam.Tabixfile):

    def __init__(self, filename, mode='r', *args, **kwargs):
        pysam.Tabixfile.__init__(self, filename, mode=mode, *args, **kwargs)
        self.x = 'foo'
```

but this still raises `TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters`.

This class is actually implemented in Cython; the constructor code is below:

```
cdef class Tabixfile:
    '''*(filename, mode='r')*

    opens a :term:`tabix file` for reading. A missing
    index (*filename* + ".tbi") will raise an exception.
    '''
    def __cinit__(self, filename, mode = 'r', *args, **kwargs ):
        self.tabixfile = NULL
        self._open( filename, mode, *args, **kwargs )
```

I read through the [Cython documentation on `__cinit__` and `__init__`](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/special_methods.html#initialisation-methods-cinit-and-init) which says

> Any arguments passed to the constructor will be passed to both the
>   `__cinit__()` method and the `__init__()` method. **If you anticipate
>   subclassing your extension type in Python, you may find it useful to
>   give the `__cinit__()` method `*` and `**` arguments** so that it can
>   accept and ignore extra arguments. Otherwise, any Python subclass
>   which has an `__init__()` with a different signature will have to
>   override `__new__()` [1](http://www.cgat.org/~andreas/documentation/pysam/api.html#pysam.Tabixfile) as well as `__init__()`, which the writer of
>   a Python class wouldn’t expect to have to do.

The pysam developers did take the care to add `*args` and `**kwargs` to the `Tabixfile.__cinit__` method, *and* my subclass `__init__` matches the signature of `__cinit__` so I do not understand why I'm unable to override the initialization of `Tabixfile`.

I'm developing with Python 3.3.1, Cython v.0.19.1, and pysam v.0.7.5.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The documentation is a little confusing here, in that it assumes that you're familiar with using `__new__` and `__init__`.

The `__cinit__` method is roughly equivalent to a `__new__` method in Python.*

Like `__new__`, `__cinit__` is *not* called by your `super().__init__`; it's called before Python even gets to your subclass's `__init__` method. The reason `__cinit__` needs to handle the signature of your subclass `__init__` methods is the exact same reason `__new__` does.

If your subclass does explicitly call `super().__init__`, that looks for an `__init__` method in a superclass—again, like `__new__`, a `__cinit__` is not an `__init__`. So, unless you've *also* defined an `__init__`, it will pass through to `object`.

---

You can see the sequence with the following code.

cinit.pyx:

```
cdef class Foo:
    def __cinit__(self, a, b, *args, **kw):
        print('Foo.cinit', a, b, args, kw)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        print('Foo.init', args, kw)
```

init.py:

```
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
import cinit

class Bar(cinit.Foo):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
        print('Bar.new', args, kw)
        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kw)
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        print('Bar.init', a, b, c, d)
        super().__init__(a, b, c, d)

b = Bar(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

When run, you'll see something like:

```
Bar.new (1, 2, 3, 4) {}
Foo.cinit 1 2 (3, 4) {}
Bar.init 1 2 3 4
Foo.init (1, 2, 3, 4) {}
```

---

So, the right fix here depends on what you're trying to do, but it's one of these:

1. Add an `__init__` method to the Cython base class.
2. Remove the `super().__init__` call entirely.
3. Change the `super().__init__` to not pass any params.
4. Add an appropriate `__new__` method to the Python subclass.

I suspect in this case it's #2 you want.

---

* It's worth noting that `__cinit__` definitely isn't *identical* to `__new__`. Instead of getting a `cls` parameter, you get a partially-constructed `self` object (where you can trust `__class__` and C attributes but not Python attributes or methods), the `__new__` methods of all classes in the MRO have already been called before any `__cinit__`; the `__cinit__` of your bases gets called automatically instead of manually; you don't get to return a different object besides the one that's been requested; etc. It's just that it's called before the `__init__`, and expected to take pass-through parameters, in the same way as `__new__` is.

Comment: Your demo code really clarifies the control flow. Thank you for taking the time to add that. I went with removing `super().__init__` and it worked beautifully and does what I had expected to happen in my own attempts.

Answer (score 1):

I would have commented rather than posting an answer but I don't have enough StackOverflow foo as yet.

@abarnert's post is excellent and very helpful. I would just add a few pysam specifics here as I have just done subclassing on pysam.AlignmentFile in a very similar way.

Option #4 was the cleanest/easiest choice which meant only changes in my own subclass __new__ to filter out the unknown params:

```
def __new__(cls, file_path, mode, label=None, identifier=None, *args, **kwargs):
    # Suck up label and identifier unknown to pysam.AlignmentFile.__cinit__
    return super().__new__(cls, file_path, mode, *args, **kwargs)
```

It should also be noted that the pysam file classes don't seem to have explicit __init__ method's, so you also need to omit param pass through as that goes straight to object.__init__ which does not accept parameters:

```
def __init__(self, label=None, identifier=None, *args, **kwargs):
    # Handle subclass params/attrs here
    # pysam.AlignmentFile doesn't have an __init__ so passes straight through to
    # object which doesn't take params. __cinit__ via new takes care of params
    super(pysam.AlignmentFile, self).__init__()
```